# How do I get my code to calculate a value from javascript and display the answer in html?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, calculation

I am trying to create code something that calculates the ddf (daily water flow) from a household based on the type of household, number of bedrooms, number of occupants, and floor area.

Right now I have completed the code for a single family with any number of bedrooms and occupants (no code for floor area yet and other types of homes). But it is not showing the answer or calculating it.

The `if` statements are based on guidelines for calculating water flow based on the info.

```html
 bedrooms=document.getElementsById("bedrooms").innerHTML;
```

Comment: Check your operators

Comment: You want `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`

Comment: Also it's `getElementById` not `getElementsById` notice there is no `s`, you should be seeing errors in the console about that. Among other typos

Comment: Learn to debug. The browser already tells you a lot of things when it encounters a problem, you just need to learn what it's trying to tell you by learning to understand the errors in the console. Using the [`console`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) can help you see what values your variables have and what properties or methods an object has. It's one of the best tools you can have as a developer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the input value, you should use [.value](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

Also, you are using a single `=` as your operator, which will always return true. Should be `if(residence == "single")`.

It also looks like you are trying to get an element that doesn't exist in order to set the information. Try creating a tag with the Id `ddf` such as `<p id=\'ddf\'><\/p>`.

You also have some typos in your code you should check. Many of these errors could be found with the console fairly quickly. You should get familiar with the [Chrome Developer Console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open).

Answer (score 1):

So, you've got some issues with your code.

`(residence = single)` returns error cause single is undefined.

You didn't create an element with `ddf` id.

The way to get value from inputs is `.value()` and not `innerHTML`.

You have typo's with `getElementsById`, should be `getElementById`.

```js
function calcDDF() {
var ddf=0;
let bedrooms=document.getElementById("bedrooms").value;
let occupants=document.getElementById("occupants").value;
let residence=document.getElementById("residence").value;

if (residence == 'single') {

  if (bedrooms == 1 && occupants == 2 || occupants == null) {
    ddf=700;
  }
  if (bedrooms == 1 && occupants > 2) {
    ddf=occupants*350;
  }
  if (bedrooms == 2 && occupants == 3 || occupants == null) {
    ddf=1000;
  }
  if (bedrooms == 2 && occupants > 3) {
    ddf=occupants*350;
  }
  if (bedrooms == 3 && occupants == 3.75 || occupants == null) {
    ddf=1300;
  }
  if (bedrooms == 3 && occupants > 3.75) {
    ddf=occupants*350;
  }
  if (bedrooms == 4 && occupantss == bedrooms + 0.5 || occupants == null) {
    ddf=1600+((bedrooms-4)*300);
  }
  if (bedrooms => 4 && occupants > bedrooms + 0.5) {
    ddf=occupants*350;
  }
}
  document.getElementById("ddf").innerHTML = ddf;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="bedrooms" placeholder="Number of Bedrooms" />
<input type="number" id="occupants" placeholder="Number of Occupants" />
<input type="number" id="area" placeholder="Floor Area (m&sup2)"/>


<select name="type of residence" id="residence">
  <option value=""disabled selected>Select the Type of Residence</option>
  <option value="single">Single Family Dwelling</option>
  <option value="multi">Multi Family</option>
  <option value="luxury">Luxury Home</option>
  <option value="cottage">Seasonal Cottage</option>
  <option value="mobile">Mobile Home</option>
</select>

<button onclick="calcDDF()">Calculate DDF</button>

<br>

<p id="ddf"></p>
```